# How to post on a friends wall with GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm using GraphAPI for posting to a friend's wall but I'm unable to do it. 
I'm trying the below link:

> http://graph.facebook.com/friendID/feed

Can anyone help me how to post to your friend's wall?

Answer (score 1):

As of february, you can't post content to a friend's wall using the API - see here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/#february-2013

> Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API We will remove
>   the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API.
>   Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is
>   different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the
>   target_id user is different from the session user, will fail.

You can post links using the FB.ui function w/ the 'to' parameter set to a friend's id, however.

Answer (score 0):

See the following change from 6th March 2013, posted on the list of completed changes in the Facebook Developers' Roadmap:

```
Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API
We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail.
If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.
```